# Area of circle bounded by x,y limits

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, circles

I need to obtain the area of a disc centered at $(x_0, y_0)$ with radius $r$, that is bounded in $x, y$ by the box defined by the limits:

$$(x_{\min}, x_{\max}), (y_{\min}, y_{\max})$$

This means that the circle can be entirely included within the box (left) or partially (right):

[image]

The double integral would need look something like this:

$$
\int_{x_{\min}}^{x_{\max}} \int_{y_{\min}}^{y_{\max}} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy
$$

But I don't know what is the form of the $f(x,y)$ function.

PD: I'm coming from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58596873/1391441).

Comment: A circle doesn't have a (non-zero) area. A disc does.

Comment: $f(x,y)$ has value $1$ if $(x,y)$ lies in the disc, and $0$ otherwise. But that's not helpful. What you need to work out is the actual integration domain, i.e. change the bounds of your integral so that the integrand becomes simply $1\cdot dxdy$.

Comment: I have answered to your original post.

Comment: Thank you @VasilyMitch I just saw your answer. I'll check it out in a couple of hours and report there how it went.

Comment: I think that in this problem is posible used Green Theorem

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Instead of integration, I would consider doing this in a different way. If you draw line segments from the center of the circle to both endpoints of the arc and to the inscribed square corners, you cut the area you want into 3 triangles and a sector.

The areas of triangles can be easily computed by Heron's formula, since you know the vertices and hence you know the lengths of the sides.

The area of the sector only depends on the amount of radians in the forming angle, which you can also compute straight from the coordinates and the center...

---